# SSRS Evaluate two different data types in an expression and give different response in header of the report

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need to Evaluate two different data types in an expression and give different response in header of the report.

For example if the parameter = x or z I need the header to display with  "X 25%" or if the data = z I need it to display z-50%.

=IIF(Parameters!Business.Value = "X", "X 25%" OR Parameters!Business.Value = "Z", "Z 50%", Parameters!Business.Value ) & " Inforce Excess Of Loss By Location State "

Comment: There is no question here and you IIF statement is hard to understand what you where trying to achieve. Please read the following guide on how to ask a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use nested IIFs to accomplish what you want.

```
=IIF(Parameters!Business.Value = "X", "X 25%", 
    IIF(Parameters!Business.Value = "Z", "Z 50%", Parameters!Business.Value )) & 
" Inforce Excess Of Loss By Location State "
```

But if would be easier to use the SWITCH statement, which is a little more like a CASE statement.

```
=SWITCH( 
        Parameters!Business.Value = "X", "X 25%",
        Parameters!Business.Value = "Z", "Z 50%",
        True, Parameters!Business.Value) & 
    " Inforce Excess Of Loss By Location State "
```

This reads If Bus = x then X 25%, else if Bus = x then X 25%, else Bus.Value.